# Low data mode doesnt stay enabled macos

Tags: macos, wifi, network

So, I enabled low data mode for my mobile hotspot (android). When i reconnect, it isn't enabled. However, it just does not persist a change of wifi network.

Here i enabled it:
[image: i enabled it]

And after disconnecting and reconnecting it is disabled once again:
[image]

This uses up more of my mobile data (android, so it cannot auto-detect the hotspot), how to fix this? I can use terminal/unix functions if necessary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me it does not remember even with MacBook and iPhone.

Comment: Still the case in Ventura 13.4.1

Comment: Confirmed that it's still the case, even when connecting to an iPhone. Disappointing behaviour.

Comment: I have the opposite problem. My iPhone wifi low data keeps turning on a while after I turn it off!! Been doing it for years, cant find a solution or reason...